# PageSpeed insights v5 returning different results depending on URL

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Google PageSpeed Insights API is returning results in a different format for different URLs

This URL
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://www.harryanddavid.com&strategy=desktop 
Returns page speed in the format FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS

And this URL
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://www.harryanddavid.com&strategy=desktop
Returns page speed in the format: firstContentfulPaint

Both calls to the API should return results in the same format.

Both returned FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT format until Friday, June 7, 2019